# airflow task specific failure notification

Tags: airflow

I have dag, with multiple tasks, each task has different owner. When a task fails, I want to notify the respective owner.

I have tried the following, where I create the `DAG` and pass the `default_args`, and in `default_args`, I mention the `email_id`, but this sends email to only a single user if any of the tasks fail, I know I can add multiple users, but there is no exclusivity with this option. Is there a way to add email at task level?

```py
default_args = {
    "retries": 1,
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email": ['abc@gmail.com'],
    "get_logs": True,
    "concurrency": 1,
    "max_active_runs": 1,
    "startup_timeout_seconds": 3600,
    "labels": {'managedby': 'airflow'},
    "on_failure_callback": on_failure_callback_slack
}

dag = DAG(dag_id="abc", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="30 20 * * *", start_date="2023-07-05")
```

Comment: you can set `on_failure_callback` at the task level i.e pass `on_failure_callback` each task you want to have failure callback

Comment: Okay, so I can pass different email I’d also at task level?

Answer (score 0):

You can set email_on_failure and email on every task once you need it different from default_args.

for example, task1, task2 has different emails, and task3 will inherited from default_args

```
task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    email_on_failure=True,
    email=['123@gmail.com'],
    python_callable=python_func1,
)

task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    email_on_failure=True,
    email=['def@gmail.com'],
    python_callable=python_func2,
)

task3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task3',
        python_callable=python_func3,
    )
```